# I have to develope a function that sorts a list of string by the number of vocals in ascending order and if there is a tie,by the first vocal

Tags: python, string, list

For example if:

```
a = ['Seven', 'SOS', 'Bye-bye', 'The', 'One', 'An', 'By',
'Eleven']
```

the function may return:

```
['By', 'An', 'SOS', 'The', 'One', 'Seven', 'Bye-bye', 'Eleven']
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: yes ,sort based on the number of vocals in each string, and if there is a tie for position of the first vocal

Comment: @LuigiMilan Then the output should be this: ```['An', 'By', 'One', 'SOS', 'The', 'Seven', 'Eleven', 'Bye-bye']``` and not what you have provided.

Comment: @Ram Minor correction: At least in my language vocals are defined as `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` and `u`. Then `'By'` has no vocals and comes first.

Comment: @Matthias In English they are called vowels.

Comment: @Ram You're right. Wikipedia says for the english language: "sometimes y". So it's up to the author of the question to specify what they regard as vowel. Other languages might have even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `sort` or `sorted` you have to define a key function for the comparison. This key function has to give back a tuple of the number of vocals and the position of the first vocal.

```
a = ['Seven', 'SOS', 'Bye-bye', 'The', 'One', 'An', 'By', 'Eleven']

def key_function(s, vowels='aeiou'):
    count = sum(c in vowels for c in s.lower())
    first = min((i for (i, c) in enumerate(s.lower()) if c in vowels), default=-1)
    print(count, first)
    return count, first



result = sorted(a, key=lambda s: key_function(s))
print(result)
```

This gives you `['By', 'An', 'SOS', 'The', 'One', 'Seven', 'Bye-bye', 'Eleven']`.

Uncomment the `print(count, first)` if you want to see the resulting values of the key function.

---

Using an extended vowel set with

```
result = sorted(a, key=lambda s: key_function(s, vowels='aeiouy'))
```

gives you `['An', 'SOS', 'By', 'The', 'One', 'Seven', 'Eleven', 'Bye-bye']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
vowels = "aeiou"

#getting number of vocals for each element in string
def countvocals(s):
    count = 0
    for i in s:
        if i in vowels:
            count += 1
    return count

#sorting list
def sortlist(x,y):
    zipped = zip(x,y)
    zipped=[x for x in zipped]
    zipped.sort(key = lambda x:x[1])
    return [a for (a,b) in zipped]

a = ['Seven', 'SOS', 'Bye-bye', 'The', 'One', 'An', 'By','Eleven']
b=[]
for i in a:
    b.append(countvocals(i))

print(sortlist(a,b))
```